# How do I update data in a SmoothieChart without spamming the the second value in TimeSeries?

Tags: javascript, json, smoothie.js

I want to build some kind of stock trading website using JSON

```
function getJSON(_url, _type) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", _url, true);
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status == 200 && request.readyState == 4) {
            Callback(JSON.parse(request.responseText), _type);
        } else
            error("reach");
    };
    request.send(null);
}
```

and a callback function to get data.

```
function Callback(_data, _type) {

    switch (_type) {
        case 1.1:
            initAktien(_data);
            break;
        case 1.2:
            updateAktien(_data);
            break;
    }
}
```

In order to visualize the stocks I'm using SmoothieChart.

```
var lines = [];
var smoothie = new SmoothieChart({
    tooltip: true, millisPerPixel: 50, minValueScale: 0,
    grid: {fillStyle: '#99d6ff', strokeStyle: '#6c7d82', verticalSections: 8, borderVisible: false},
    labels: {disabled: true, fontSize: 9}, minValue: 0, horizontalLines: [{color: '#000000', lineWidth: 1, value: 0}, {color: '#4d0f00', lineWidth: 2, value: 100}]
});
smoothie.streamTo(document.getElementById("aktien-grafik"), 500);
```

A little heads up in case you're wondering: "Aktien" means stocks, "preis" means price, and "anzahlVerfügbar" means available amount. I got this code from someone else and I'm supposed to "fix" it. That's why it's partially in German.

```
function initAktien(_data) {
    var stocks = document.getElementById("aktien");
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");

    for (var i = 0; i <= _data.length - 1; i++) {
        var stockoption = document.createElement("option");
        stockoption.innerHTML = _data[i].name;
        stocks.appendChild(stockoption);
    }

    for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        var amountoption = document.createElement("option");
        amountoption.innerHTML = j;
        amount.appendChild(amountoption);
    }
}

function updateAktien(_data) {
    var select = document.getElementById("aktien").selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("kurs").innerHTML = _data[select].preis;
    document.getElementById("anz").innerHTML = _data[select].anzahlVerfuegbar;

    //spam is because of here
    lines.push(new TimeSeries());
    lines[select].append(new Date().getTime(), _data[select].preis);
    smoothie.addTimeSeries(lines[select], {lineWidth: 2, strokeStyle: "#000000"});
}
```

I can render the graph just fine and I even get an overlay displaying the timestamp and the and the price and the time. Unfortunately it spams the price in the overlay which slows the site down quite fast. Removing the overlay doesn't solve the problem since the price is appended nonstop
somewhere at the point I marked. I don't know how to keep the data updating and the chart drawing without spamming that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's the best solution, but it works. It's somewhat redundant code.

```
function initAktien(_data) {
    var stocks = getID("aktien");
    var amount = getID("amount");

    for (var i = 0; i <= _data.length - 1; i++) {
        var stockoption = document.createElement("option");
        stockoption.innerHTML = _data[i].name;
        stocks.appendChild(stockoption);

        lines.push(new TimeSeries());
        lines[i].append(new Date().getTime(), _data[i].preis.toFixed(2));
        smoothie.addTimeSeries(lines[i], {lineWidth: 2, strokeStyle: "#000000"});
    }
}

function updateAktien(_data) {
    var select = getID("aktien").selectedIndex;
    getID("kurs").innerHTML = _data[select].preis.toFixed(2);
    getID("anz").innerHTML = _data[select].anzahlVerfuegbar;

    //Grafik update
    lines[select].append(new Date().getTime(), _data[select].preis.toFixed(2));
}
```